# How to differentiate between text and number in scanned text?

Tags: java, android, ocr

I am using Microsoft Cognitive Services Computer Vision Api as an OCR service to read food menus.

I am able to scan the menu successfully but now i am want to save the dish name part and price part in two different arrays.

The result now after scanning is totally devastated because of special characters like rupee sign,parenthesis,menu-number.

I just want the dish name and price without rupee sign.
Can someone tell me how could I achieve that?
Here is [github link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-vision-android) and some code that could help you in assisting me:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
        super.onPostExecute(data);
        // Display based on error existence

        if (e != null) {
            mEditText.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            this.e = null;
        } else {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            OCR r = gson.fromJson(data, OCR.class);

            String result = "";
            for (Region reg : r.regions) {
                for (Line line : reg.lines) {
                    for (Word word : line.words) {
                        result += word.text + " ";
                    }
                    result += "\n";
                }
                result += "\n\n";
            }

            mEditText.setText(result);
        }
        mButtonSelectImage.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

What I want is:

1) I don't want any of these special characters in result.

2) I want to save the dish name and price in two different arrays.

[Here are the screen shots of the output and the menu.](https://postimg.org/gallery/1ewhhjc2s/)

Comment: Prima facie use pattern. or if you can provide sample text I can suggest more.

Comment: Please provide output you got, and it follow pattern or not. It is very important to check wether gson output is not impacted with Locale. Otherwise its more challenging.

Comment: @SouravGanguly Please see edit. Screenshots are added at the bottom of question.

Comment: @MaherAbuthraa Please see edit. Screenshots are added at the bottom of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks for your help guys!!

I obtained only characters by using this regex:

```
resultString = result.replaceAll("\\P{L}", " ");
```

and only numbers using this regex:

```
resultNumber = result.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```